# RESTEasy Interceptors

Tags: java, json, rest, resteasy

I have configured an interceptor for my REST Services as follows

```
@Before("execution(* com.test.controllers.*.*(..))")
public void logBefore(final JoinPoint joinPoint) { }
```

I am sending a JSON as my request to my service. And this is logging my request JSON. Now, in the case of an invalid JSON, the web application will throw an exception and will not log the request JSON. Is there a way I can log the request JSON even before it gets parsed?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply @Priority annotation to your interceptor. A collection of built-in priority constants is defined in [javax.ws.rs.Priorities](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/Priorities.html).

The interceptor that parses the request JSON use `Priorities.ENTITY_CODER = 4000`.If no priority is specified, the default is `Priorities.USER = 5000`. The lower the number the higher the priority. Use the @Priority and take any numeric value you wish between 3000 and 4000 like:

```
private static final int LOG_BEFORE = 3500;

@Priority(LOG_BEFORE)        
public void logBefore(final JoinPoint joinPoint) { }
```